# How to query users for users who are not in a relation with another user on parse.com

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform

I am trying to get all users who are not in the current users following relation.

```
    var followingRelation = PFUser.currentUser().objectForKey("following") as PFRelation!
    var following = followingRelation.query()

    var query = PFUser.query()
    query.whereKey("objectId", notEqualTo: PFUser.currentUser().objectId)
    query.whereKey("objectId", doesNotMatchQuery: following)
    query.whereKey("currentLocation", nearGeoPoint: userLocation, withinMiles: 50)
    query.limit = 10
```

This gives me a bad type for not in query error, which i understand. I can get all of the users in the following relation but cant seem to get the users not in the following relation. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Post your solution as an answer, you can mark it as correct too. It will allow others that find your question to see that it has a valid answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to use, query.whereKey("objectId",doesNotMatchKey: "objectId", inQuery: following) and worked like a charm